# Customizing Chatter Email templates

Tags: chatter

I have a requirement to customize the Chatter Email templates.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to customize chatter email templates. there has only been ideas posted for salesforce to make it customizable.